# Print a nested list line by line - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, printing, nested-lists

`A = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]`

I am trying my best to print `A` of the form:

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
4 5 6
```

That is in different lines, but I am unable to do so without all the elements in different lines. This is my code so far:

```
for r in A:
   for t in r:
       print(t,)
    print
```

This is my output:

```
1
2
3
2
3
4
4
5
6
```

It seems really simple, and I think a minor change would do it. Thanks!

Comment: check out my one-liner solution below. it doesnot have to be complex

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a simple for loop and `" ".join()` mapping each `int` in the nested list to a `str` with `map()`.

**Example:**

```
>>> ys = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
>>> for xs in ys:
...     print(" ".join(map(str, xs)))
... 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```

The difference here is that we can support arbitrary lengths of inner lists.

---

The reason your example did not work as expected is because your inner loop is iterating over each element of the sub-list;

```
for r in A:  # r = [1, 2, 3]
    for t in r:  # t = 1 (on first iteration)
        print(t,)
    print
```

And `print()` by default prints new-line characters at the end unless you use: `print(end="")` I believe if you were using Python 2.x `print t,` would work. For example:

```
>>> ys = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
>>> for xs in ys:
...     for x in xs:
...             print x,
...     print
... 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```

But `print(x,)` would not work as you intended it; Python 2.x or 3.x

Answer (score 5):

**Better than the accepted answer**

try this one liner
**`[print(a) for a in A];`** I love one liner! Give an upvote if you like it

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
[print(a) for a in A];
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[4, 5, 6]
```

if you don't want to see `[]` in the printout, then do
**`[print(*a) for a in A];`**

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
[print(*a) for a in A];
1 2 3
2 3 4
4 5 6
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for r in A:
    print '%d %d %d' % tuple(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Method-1 :**

We can use list comprehension and `.join()` operator.

```
>>> my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]

>>> for item in my_list:
        print ' '.join(str(x) for x in item)

1 2 3
2 3 4
4 5 6
```

**Method-2 :**

```
>>> my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]

>>> for item in my_list:
        for x in item:
            print x,
        print 

1 2 3
2 3 4
4 5 6
```

Inner `print` with a comma ensures that inner list's elements are printed in a single line.
Outer `print` ensures that for the next inner list, it prints in next line.

Answer (score 1):

`print` without trailing comma will print a newline character.

```
for r in A:
    for t in r:
        print t,
    print
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Python 3.x:

```
print(*('{} {} {}'.format(*r) for r in A), sep='\n')
```

or:

```
print(*('%d %d %d' % tuple(r) for r in A), sep='\n')
```

If not, you can import Python 3.x's print function from the `__future__` module.

Answer (score 1):

The same question was answered by Jim Fasarakis Hilliard in [Print list of lists in separate lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872341/print-list-of-lists-in-separate-lines).

In Python 3.x we can use:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]

for i in A:
        print(*i)
```

And the corresponding output is:

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
4 5 6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for [a,b,c] in A:
   print(a,b,c)
```

This might help.
But if you have more number of elements in the lists or if elements in the nested lists are variable,This won't work.
Below code will print all elements of a nested lists in single line.

```
for b in A:
    for p in b:
         print(p,end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `yield from`

```
lst = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7]]
 
def f(lst ):
    yield from lst


for x in f(lst):
    print(*x)
```

```
1 3 4
2 5 7

[Program finished]
```