# Print list of lists in separate lines

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, printing, nested-lists

I have a list of lists:

```
a = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7]]
```

I want the output in the following format:

```
1 3 4
2 5 7
```

I have tried it the following way , but the outputs are not in the desired way:

```
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        print(j, sep=' ')
```

Outputs:

```
1
3
4
2
5
7
```

While changing the print call to use `end` instead:

```
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        print(j, end = ' ')
```

Outputs:

```
1 3 4 2 5 7
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Iterate through every sub-list in your original list and *unpack* it in the print call with `*`:

```
a = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7]]
for s in a:
    print(*s)
```

The separation is by default set to `' '` so there's no need to explicitly provide it. This prints:

```
1 3 4
2 5 7
```

In your approach you were iterating for every element in every sub-list and printing that individually. By using `print(*s)` you *unpack* the list inside the print call, this essentially translates to:

```
print(1, 3, 4)  # for s = [1, 3, 4]
print(2, 5, 7)  # for s = [2, 5, 7]
```

Comment: How would you print the transpose of this without libraries?

Answer (score 16):

oneliner:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str,sl)) for sl in l))
```

explanation:
you can convert `list` into `str` by using join function:

```
l = ['1','2','3']
' '.join(l) # will give you a next string: '1 2 3'
'.'.join(l) # and it will give you '1.2.3'
```

so, if you want linebreaks you should use new line symbol.
But join accepts only list of strings. For converting list of things to list of strings, you can apply `str` function for each item in list:

```
l = [1,2,3]
' '.join(map(str, l)) # will return string '1 2 3'
```

And we apply this construction for each sublist `sl` in list `l`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
>>> lst = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7]]
>>> for sublst in lst:
...     for item in sublst:
...             print item,        # note the ending ','
...     print                      # print a newline
... 
1 3 4
2 5 7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def print_list(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if isinstance(s[i],list):
            k=s[i]
            print_list(k)
        else:
            print(s[i])
            
s=[[1,2,[3,4,[5,6]],7,8]]
print_list(s)
```

you could enter lists within lists within lists ..... and yet everything will be printed as u expect it to be.

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: Please read the question again since this answer does not solve the issue of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is pretty simple:

```
a = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7]]   # defines the list
    
for i in range(len(a)):      # runs for every "sub-list" in a
    for j in a[i]:           # gives j the value of each item in a[i]
        print(j, end=" ")    # prints j without going to a new line
    print()                  # creates a new line after each list-in-list prints
```

output

```
1 3 4 
2 5 7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7]]
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        print(j, end = ' ')
    print('',sep='\n')
```

output:

```
1 3 4
2 5 7
```

Comment: Pls add some description to your answer and explain how it works and solves the problem.

Comment: Your last print is quite confusing for no reason. `print('',sep='\n') == print()`...

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative method to display list rather than arranging them in sub-list:

```
tick_tack_display = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

loop_start = 0
count = 0
while loop_start < len(tick_tack_display):
     print(tick_tack_display[loop_start], end = '')
     count +=1
     if count - 3 == 0:
       print("\n")
       count = 0
     loop_start += 1
```

OUTPUT :

```
123
456
789
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7]]
 
def f(lst ):
    yield from lst


for x in f(lst):
    print(*x)
```

using "yield from"...

Produces Output

```
1 3 4
2 5 7

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier one-liner way:

```
a = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7]] # your data
[print(*x) for x in a][0] # one-line print
```

And the result will be as you want it:

```
1 3 4
2 5 7
```

Make sure you add the `[0]` to the end of the list comprehension, otherwise, the last line would be a list of `None` values equal to the length of your list.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way will be:

```
a = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7]]
for i in a:
  for j in i:
      print(j, end = " ")
  print('\n')
```