# How can I append \n at the end of the list in list comperhansion

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have this code:

```
def table(h, w):
    table = [['.' for i in range(w)] for j in range(h)]
    return table
```

which returns this

```
[
['.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.']
]
```

How to make it return this?

```
[
    ['.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.']
]
```

Comment: They are the same ? list contains 3 list  each contains 3 points? it's a matter of printing?

Comment: what exactly do you mean? it returns that when print it out? so the output of: 
```python
print(table(2, 2))
```
would be:
```
[
[['.', '.'],['.', '.']]
]
```
?

Comment: You want to change the way the data in the list gets printed, not the content of the list. If you really want to obtain this output, you will have to do the printing yourself...

Comment: [Printing sublists on different lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872341/print-list-of-lists-in-separate-lines)

Comment: try playing with `pprint.pprint(a, width=...)` instead of print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (only) way to do it is actually to format the result (list type) to a string :

```
def table(h, w):
    table = [['.' for i in range(w)] for j in range(h)]
    return table
def format_table(table_):
    return "[\n" + ''.join(["\t" + str(line) + ",\n" for line in table_]) + "]"
print(format_table(table(3,3)))
```

Output :

```
[
    ['.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.'],
]
```