# How to convert list of lists to a string with a new line

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion

I have this code:

```
def table(h, w):
    table = [['.' for i in range(w)] for j in range(h)]
    return table
```

which returns this

```
[
['.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.']
]
```

How to make it return this?

```
....
....
....
....
```

Comment: Try using list join

Comment: What would *this* be? A string? Printing it on the screen?

Comment: You print the representation of the table. If you want your own format, then write some code (you'll need `for` loops). A one-liner could look like this: `print('\n'.join(''.join(row) for row in table))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can't* directly return something like that. That's not associated with any data type. However, you can create a function that formats the output like that given your current representation of a table:

```py
def print_table(table):
    for row in table:
        print(''.join(row))
```

Which gives you your desired output:

```py
....
....
....
....
```

EDIT: Now that I think about it, it's possible. But you'll only be returning the string representation of your table and not its structure (which I assumed you needed):

```
def table(h, w):
    table = ''
    for row in range(h):
        table += '.' * w + '\n'
    return table
```

Answer (score 1):

Question already asked [How can I append \n at the end of the list in list comperhansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58472978/how-can-i-append-n-at-the-end-of-the-list-in-list-comperhansion/58473237)

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58472978/how-can-i-append-n-at-the-end-of-the-list-in-list-comperhansion/58473237#58473237) :

> The (only) way to do it is actually to format the result (list type)
>   to a string :
>
> ```
> def table(h, w):
>     table = [['.' for i in range(w)] for j in range(h)]
>     return table
> def format_table(table_):
>   return "[\n" + ''.join(["\t" + str(line) + ",\n" for line in table_]) + "]"
> print(format_table(table(3,3)))
> ```
>
> Output :
>
> ```
> [
>   ['.', '.', '.'],
>   ['.', '.', '.'],
>   ['.', '.', '.'],
> ]
> ```

For this one :

```
def format_table(table_):
    return ''.join([''.join([e for e in line]) + ",\n" for line in table_])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```py
def table(h, w):
    table = '\n'.join(['.'*w]) for j in range(h)])
    return table
```

Comment: `''.join(['.' for i in range(w)])` can just be `'.' * w`

Comment: `''.join(['.' for i in range(w)])` - that part is overly complicated and might even be wrong. You'll output a `.` even if there might be other content in the list later.