# Battleships Board

Tags: python, arrays, nested

How do I create an array for my 10x10 battleships board?

```
def battleships_playerboard():
    player_board = [
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],

    ]
```

I don't think I'm getting the concept of this right, because whenever I try to print it it prints out

```
print(player_board)
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Please add the code that you use for printing.

Comment: add this to the bottom of `def battleships_playerboard()`  `for i in player_board:
        print(i)`

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/38872499/3250423 give the output you are looking for?

Comment: You can't access local variable in function from outside. so you can return `player_board` from `battleships_playerboard()` function then you can print it by calling the function  `print(battleships_playerboard())`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `player_board` already looks like a usable array

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
Your title is about an internal data structure, but your question appears to be for the output formatting.  That formatting is covered by *many* on-line references: documentation, tutorials, etc.  We expect you to do your research before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the module "pprint":

```
from pprint import pprint

def battleships_playerboard():
  player_board = [
    ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
    ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
    ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
    ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
    ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
    ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
    ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
    ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
    ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
    ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
      ]

  pprint(player_board)

battleships_playerboard()
```

This should return

```
 [['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
```