# Creating a table in Python without using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of Lists, that I would like to convert into a table without using any packages like Pandas

Input:

```
list_of_lists = [[nikola, 100],[albert, 200],[steve, 300]]
```

Output:

I want to have the inventors names in a table below a column header "inventors" and the values associated with each below a column header "net worth"

```
Inventor Net Worth
nikola   100
albert   200
steve    300
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print list in table format in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17279059/6045800)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print list of lists in separate lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38872341/6045800)

Comment: You don't need `zip`. Just `for row in list_of_lists: print(*row)`