# First. second and third items of nested lists in 1 raw:

Tags: python

I am beginner in python

I have a list of nested lists of strings:

```
mylist = [['ab','cde','efgh'],['ijk','lm','mno'],['p','qrst','uv']]
```

i need to print first, second and third items of each list in 1 raw and each of column should be right-justified:

Output:

```
  ab, ijk,    p
 cde,  lm, qrst
efgh, mno,   uv
```

Can you help me how can i do this?

Comment: Take a look at this link -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/30522343/8735916 . Possible duplicate

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework task so I did the easier bit.

```
l = [["ab","cde","efgh"],["ijk","lm","mno"],["p","qrst","uv"]]

# Assume the each list is the same length
for i in range(len(l[0])):
    print(",".join([ele[i] for ele in l]))
```

It outputs the list in the way you want, except it isn't right aligned. I'll leave the alignment up to you :)